# cross compile (arm-none-eabi-as) arm assembly error "junk at end of line /" or undefined symbol

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, assembly, arm, cross-compiling

Hi while i cross compile an startup.s file
(arm-none-eabi-as file.s)
(*-gcc)

I am getting in each commentary line some errors
- junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `/`

when i delete the // some comment lines i get
errors about undefined symbols even i defined them at beginning of the file.

anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: #define I_BIT  0x80
...
msr     CPSR_c, #ARM_MODE_IRQ | I_BIT | F_BIT

Comment: You can't use C headers in assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(arm) Assembler does not support // comments or defines, you have to use .equ and @ for comments.  If you let gcc parse it you can put C isms like that into your assembler.  Personally I avoid such C isms and keep the assembler clean.   if you cannot do that or need includes with defines for example let gcc pre-process the file before sending it to gas.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use macros or C comments, then you have to preprocess the source file with the C preprocessor. The C preprocessor removes comments and interprets macros. The GNU assembler should run the C preprocessor automatically if the source file name ends with `.S`, with an *uppercase* 'S'.